# T_constant_encapsed_string issue

Tags: php

Please don't tell me to google the problem as I have already and nothing works and adding a . doesn't seem to help me either. I have tried multiple times and every way possible.

The problem I'm running into problems with line 52:

```
50 require(html-head.inc");
51 
52 echo "<h1>$title, $firstName!</h1>\n";
53 echo "</header>\n";
54 echo "<article>\n";
55 echo "<p>$firstName $lastName, <br />We appreciate your participation in ";
56 echo "our meaningless activity after your $age years of life. ";
57 echo "We will not spam your $email address, but we do plan to ";
58 echo "launch a Denial of legitimacy attack on $url. </p>\n";
59 }
60 echo "</section><!--wrapper-->\n</body>\n</html>";
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And voila, after you posted - the SO syntax highlighter shows you the error.

Comment: Give full code please. Delete line 51 from source

Answer (score 4):

Try changing this:

`require(html-head.inc");`

to this

`require("html-head.inc");`

Other than that I can't see any other errors...

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why I didn't see that before.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the starting quote in you require statement.
It should be:

```
  require("html-head.inc");
```

Answer (score 0):

In require_once you didn't write the first double quote (").